# How do I speed up my query that is creating new columns from a value in another column?

Tags: sql-server

I am not exactly sure about the phrasing of what I am requesting, but I am trying to create a query for a report and all of my values for each of my columns that I want to create are in a single column, currently.  Here is my current query:

```
SELECT [SubjectID]
    ,(SELECT [DataValue] 
      FROM [SummarySubjectDataValueAll]
      WHERE [LibraryEventID] IN (
                SELECT [LibraryEventID] 
                FROM [LibraryEvent] 
                WHERE [Name] LIKE '%First Name%')
     ) as FirstName
    ,(SELECT [DataValue] 
      FROM [SummarySubjectDataValueAll]
      WHERE [LibraryEventID] IN 
                     (SELECT [LibraryEventID] 
                      FROM [LibraryEvent] 
                       WHERE [Name] LIKE '%Last Name%')) as LastName
    ,(SELECT [DataValue] 
      FROM [SummarySubjectDataValueAll]
      WHERE [LibraryEventID] IN (
               SELECT [LibraryEventID] 
               FROM [LibraryEvent] 
               WHERE [Name] LIKE 'Primary Phone')) as Phone
    ,(SELECT [DataValue] 
      FROM [SummarySubjectDataValueAll]
      WHERE [LibraryEventID] IN (
             SELECT [LibraryEventID] 
             FROM LibraryEvent] 
             WHERE [Name] = 'Secondary Phone')) as Phone2
      ,(SELECT [DataValue] 
        FROM [SummarySubjectDataValueAll]
        WHERE [LibraryEventID] IN (
               SELECT [LibraryEventID] 
               FROM [LibraryEvent] 
               WHERE [Name] = 'Next of Kin Phone')) as KinPhone
  FROM [SummarySubjectDataValueAll]
  WHERE DataValue = @Phone
```

(Individually, they queries pull what I need and very quickly).  It is running well past 10 minutes or more to try to pull the information and I know that it is because I am making it run again the same table 6 times.  It is just failing me to recall how to do this in a more efficient manner.  Can someone please assist?  Some background on what this report is doing:  It is essentially a reverse phone directory.  I need to pull the person's information based on their phone number, which could be any of the 3 types above (Primary, secondary, or next of kin).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide the execution plan please?

Comment: SQL version?  Seems like a very simple pivot to me.

Comment: This existing query probably doesn't do what you think. It will return the _first_ entry in LibraryEvent for each field name, rather than one that matches anything in the row from the SummarySubjectDataValueAll table.

Comment: SQL Server 2012.  I can provide the estimated plan, but the actual will take a while.  I haven't let it continue to see how long it runs.  I believe I've gone to 20 minutes with it still not producing a result.

Comment: I was thinking it should be a pivot as well, but I've only ever done ones with aggregates and I do not want these to be aggregates, so I am having difficulty figuring it out.

Comment: After 15 minutes, I actually got an error:  Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.   Sagi's response is sort of putting me on the right track, but I'm still not getting EVERYTHING that I need.  I'm getting the field that has the phone number I'm searching for, but I also need all their other phone numbers to appear as well, along with the First and Last Names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply avoid all this nested selects by using conditional aggregation with `CASE EXPRESSION`  :

```
SELECT t.subjectID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.name LIKE '%First Name%' THEN t.DataValue END) as FirstName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.name LIKE '%Last Name%' THEN t.DataValue END) as LastName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.name = 'Primary Phone' THEN t.DataValue END) as Phone,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.name = 'Secondary Phone' THEN t.DataValue END) as Phone2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.name = 'Next of Kin Phone' THEN t.DataValue END) as KinPhone
FROM SummarySubjectDataValueAll t
JOIN LibraryEvent s
 ON(t.LibraryEventID = s.LibraryEventID)
GROUP BY t.subjectID
```

Comment: I'm assuming t.name should be changed to s.LibraryEvent, since that is what has the First Name, Last Name, Primary Phone, etc designations, but I'm getting the following error when I do that:Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'LibraryEvent'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'LibraryEvent'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'LibraryEvent'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'LibraryEvent'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'LibraryEvent'.

Comment: Doesn't the column called `LibraryEventID` ? I can't know what you are doing wrong.. I don't know the tables structure . @Renee'

Comment: Sorry, the LibraryEventID is the FK to the LibraryEvent table where the LibraryEvent (actual event name) is located.  The First Name, Last Name, etc. labels are "events".  The DataValue field contains the actual name values, phone number values, etc.

Comment: Strike that.  It wasn't s.LibraryEvent, it was s.Name.  Trying it now, but it's still running.  I will let you know shortly if this corrected it.  Thanks. :)

Comment: It gave me the columns I wanted, however, when I add my parameter in, it will only populate the column that the phone number is in and the other columns will be NULL (except SubjectID).  I listed my parameter statement as: WHERE t.DataValue = @Phone.  Do I need some sort of JOIN or something to get this to happen?

Comment: Why do you need this filter? Try instead of your WHERE to use the HAVING clause at the end of the query. Try adding `HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN T.DATAVALUE = @phone THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1`.

Comment: If I search by the subjectID everything populates how I want it, however, the purpose of this query is to find that ID in the first place.

Comment: No problem mate :)